# Testing react form - AssertionError

Tags: reactjs, sinon, chai, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a click on a react component that renders a form, however it fails the third test with the following error

> AssertionError: expected [Function: proxy] to have a property 'callCount' of 1, but got 0

Here's the test i wrote:

**form.test.js**

```
describe('<Form />', () => {
  it('renders without exploding', () => {
    shallow(<Form />);
  });

  it('renders an `.login_form`', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Form />);
    expect(wrapper.find('.login_form')).to.have.length(1);
  });

  it('simulates click events', () => {
    const onButtonClick = sinon.spy();
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Form handleSubmit={ onButtonClick } />,
   );
    wrapper.find('.submitBtn').simulate('click');
    expect(onButtonClick).to.have.property('callCount', 1);
  });
});
```

and the component itself:

**form.jsx**

```
function Form(props) {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={ props.handleSubmit } className='form-horizontal login_form'>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <div className='col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12'>
          <input className='form-control' type='text' id='username' value={ props.username } onChange={ props.handleUsername } placeholder='Username' required />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <div className='col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12'>
          <input className='form-control' type='password' id='password' value={ props.password } onChange={ props.handlePassword } placeholder='Password' required />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className='form-group'>
        <div className='col-md-offset-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12'>
          <button className='btn btn-block btn-default submit submitBtn' type='submit'>Log in</button>
              {
                 props.error !== '' &&
                 <p className='login_error no-margin'>
                   {props.error}
                 </p>
               }
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}

Form.propTypes = {
  username: React.PropTypes.string,
  password: React.PropTypes.string,
  error: React.PropTypes.string,
  handleUsername: React.PropTypes.func,
  handlePassword: React.PropTypes.func,
  handleSubmit: React.PropTypes.func,
};

export default Form;
```

What i am trying to do here is that i want to test that when the login button is clicked, the onSubmit handler is called. What am i doing on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to submit form this way:

```
wrapper.find("form").simulate("submit");
```